# How do I construct a table with this design in TeX?

Tags: tables

How can I construct such a table?

[image: Table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the tex code you tried so far!

Comment: To expand on the previous comment, this site isn't really a coding service.  Creating a table like the one you've shown is a common feature of any LaTeX tutorial.  We would like for you to learn how to create the table on your own.  But if there's some aspect that is giving you trouble, then please post what you have so far, and we'll be glad to help.  (You may also want to consider the opinions of the booktabs package at https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs?lang=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
leaving area (feet$^2$) & Price (100\$s) \\ \hline
text  &  text  \\
text  &  text \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The table shown in your screenshot is serviceable, in the sense that it manages to convey some information. However, overall, it looks unappealing and uninviting, making it an unexciting mental chore for readers to absorb the information the table is meant to provide.

Rather than give you suggestions for how to create unappealing and uninviting tables, I'd rather provide suggestions for creating a better-looking table.

- Don't use any vertical lines, and use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package -- such as `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\cmidrule` -- instead of `\hline` and `\cline`.
- Provide a bit more structure to the header cells, e.g., by placing the column titles and the units of measurement on separate lines. This will have the side effect of making the table narrower overall, which I think of as a good thing.
- Align the numbers in the numeric columns on their explicit or implicit decimal markers. This may be achieved by using the `S` column type that's provided by the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for \toprule and \midrule macros
\usepackage{array}      % an all-around useful package
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for 'S' column type

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ @{} S[table-format=4.0] 
                     S[table-format=3.0] 
                 @{} }
\toprule
{Living area} & {Price} \\
{(sq.\ feet)} & {(\$1000s)} \\
\midrule
2104 & 400 \\
1600 & 330 \\
2400 & 369 \\
800  &  95 \\
{$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```